# Find the mass of regular tetrahedron whose edge is 1 if its density decreases from 1 to 0 from its base to its apex.

Tags: calculus

Find the mass of  regular tetrahedron whose edge is 1 if its density decreases from 1 to 0 from its base to its apex.

My inclination is to use a triple integral and simply go about finding the volume since $$ M = \int \int \int_{R} f(x,y,z) dzdydz$$

Where $f$ is the density function. In this case I think that the density function is simply the plane $x+y+z=1$, so I would just integrate

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} \int_{0}^{1-x-y} dzdydx = \frac{1}{6}$$

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: what do you mean by edge is one?

Comment: That is the way the question is worded. I suppose it means that the length of the base is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Density is mass per unit volume, so we observe that the differential mass $dM$ of a slice of constant density $\rho$ is simply the differential thickness of the tetrahedron times the area of the cross-section.  So if the tetrahedron's density is a linear function of its side length from base to apex, and varies from $\rho = 1$ at the base to $\rho = 0$ at the apex, then the total mass is simply the integral of $dM$ over the total side length.

So let $x \in [0,1]$ be a point measured along a side length, and let the density be $\rho(x) = x$ and the cross-sectional area $A(x)$ at $x$ is simply the area of an equilateral triangle of edge length $x$; i.e., $$A(x) = x^2 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$  It follows that the differential mass of the slice is $$dM = A(x) \rho(x) \, dx = x^3 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4},$$ and its total mass is then $$M = \int_{x=0}^1 dM = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}.$$